# Google Play not able to sign-in into Clash of Clans app

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm playing [Clash of Clans](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.clashofclans) on my Android device, and I have already downloaded Google Play and signed in as well.  But when I am trying to log-in into Clash of Clans the loading ring just rotate for a while, but I am not able to sign in and save the game.

What should I do now?

Comment: Does this happen with all the games or only Clash of clans?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Google Play Games? It should be signed in,  to allow you to log in Clash of Clans to Google Play Games.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Google play games app now to log in to games.

Comment: Well if Google considered this step sometime ago requiring its app to log-in into Games, then there must be news out there to confirm this. Please quote or cite the reference.

Comment: Allstar heroes needs google play games to login, castle clash aswell, magic rush heroes too and a hell load of more games, browse the games sometimes.